# In django how to add 2000 records at a one submit button

Tags: python

There is two forms and I used StackedInline in admin.py for second model If I add 500 records at a same time then showing this error how to handle it "The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS."

Comment: please show us your attempt, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be rude but really, searching for  "django DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS" yields links to the relevant documentation in the top three results:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-number-fields

> DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS¶
>
> New in Django 1.10. Default: 1000
>
> The maximum number of parameters that may be received via GET or POST
>   before a SuspiciousOperation (TooManyFields) is raised. You can set
>   this to None to disable the check. Applications that are expected to
>   receive an unusually large number of form fields should tune this
>   setting.
>
> The number of request parameters is correlated to the amount of time
>   needed to process the request and populate the GET and POST
>   dictionaries. Large requests could be used as a denial-of-service
>   attack vector if left unchecked. Since web servers don’t typically
>   perform deep request inspection, it’s not possible to perform a
>   similar check at that level.

So maybe next time you could save everyone's time and start by reading the documention ?